# Laravel saving model without triggering events

Tags: laravel

I am interested if there is a difference between saving the model using `withoutEvents` and `saveQuietly`. What is the main difference between next two pieces of code:

```
$user = User::withoutEvents(function () use () {
    $user = User::findOrFail(1);
    $user->name = 'Victoria Faith';
    $user->save();
    return $user;
});
```

and:

```
$user = User::findOrFail(1);    
$user->name = 'Victoria Faith';    
$user->saveQuietly();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`SaveQuietly` is a wrapper for the closure `WithoutEvents` that accepts options:

```
trait SaveQuietly
{
    /**
     * Save model without triggering observers on model
     */
    public function saveQuietly(array $options = [])
    {
        return static::withoutEvents(function () use ($options) {
            return $this->save($options);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh. For some reason, I am getting an error that I am trying to save a duplicate record (Primary key restriction) when saving using `saveQuietly` which I am not getting when I use `save()` instead. The problem is I am calling this function from `...Observer` class and `updated` function, and that's why I need to `saveQuietly`

Comment: This was my bad. The problem was I called `saveQuietly` on `updating`, not on `updatED`. That's why it tried to save it two times with same ID